# Import issue in Meteor 1.6 or 1.7. Can still use "import"?

Tags: webpack, meteor, babeljs, ecma

I am working on upgrading my Meteor project and since version Meteor 1.6 onwards, we keep encountering import errors.  No matter we are using babel, webpack or ecmascript to compile.

My question is can we still using import?  If yes, which compiler is best to use?

```
import {createApp} from 'mantra-core-extra';
^^^^^^

(STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
(STDERR)     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
(STDERR)     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
```

---

I afraid that's the begin of the code in /client, as shown:

```
import {createApp} from 'mantra-core-extra';
import initContext from './configs/context';

// modules
import coreModule from './modules/core';
import loginModule from './modules/login';
import dashboardModule from './modules/dashboard';
import settingsModule from './modules/settings';
import ticketsModule from './modules/tickets';
import paymentModule from './modules/payment';
```

---

If earlier, then it will be the code at /server, which are as below:

```
import publications from './publications';
import methods from './methods';
import addInitialData from './configs/initial_adds.js';
import cron from './configs/cron.js';
import './configs/email_template.js';
import './configs/webapp.js';
```

Comment: Can you please add the lines of code you used to update?

Comment: Some examples would be:

import publications from './publications';
import methods from './methods';
import addInitialData from './configs/initial_adds.js';
import cron from './configs/cron.js';
import './configs/email_template.js';
import './configs/webapp.js';

publications();
methods();
addInitialData();
cron();

Comment: Please add this code formatted to the question. It is hardly understandable within comments.

Comment: `import {createApp} from 'mantra-core-extra';  `

> `import initContext from './configs/context';  `
  
// modules . 
`import coreModule from './modules/core';  `
import loginModule from './modules/login';  
import dashboardModule from './modules/dashboard';  
import settingsModule from './modules/settings';  
import ticketsModule from './modules/tickets';  
import paymentModule from './modules/payment';

Comment: Am so sorry, I can't seem to be able to format the question, read the formatting guide, but doesn't seem applicable

Comment: You don't need to compile anything. Meteor takes care of everything. The code you show is perfectly fine for meteor. The issue must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show the line before? And I assume all you do is run `meteor`, correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `import` isn't supported by node natively, but don't worry, Meteor looks after that for you. Your code is somehow getting run by node without being transpiled, this can happen if you are using jest or some other testing framework

Comment: Yeah the part that Meteor will take care of everything was what I experienced before 1.4.2.  But having these errors after upgraded Meteor and node version (to 8.8.1).

Comment: @ChristianFritz Yes, I ran `meteor` command

`meteor --settings settings/settings.development.json --unsafe-perm`

Comment: Any suggestion of which I should use to transpile, babel vs webpack ?

Comment: Like I said, you should *not* transpile.

Comment: My solution is to change to compile using Meteor Atmosphere with `ecmascript` package installed.

Given up on `babel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to change to compile using Meteor Atmosphere with `ecmascript` package installed. Given up on `babel` and `webpack`.